# PHP Sessions not working in background process

Tags: php, wordpress, session, payment-gateway

I have this code that when the payment gateway is successful, it will redirect to the notification url in the parameters.

```
include 'payment_information_rebill.php';

if(isset($_GET)){
    
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'url here',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
                "merchantId": "' .$_mid. '",
                "orgResponseId": "' .$_responseid. '",
                "requestId": "' .$_requestid. '",
                "amount": "' .$_verifamount. '",
                "clientId": "' .$_clientid. '",
                "clientIp": "' .$_clientip. '",
                "ipAddress": "' .$_ipaddress. '",
                "signature": "' .$_signverify. '"
        }',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Idempotency-Key: ' .$_requestid. '',
                'Authorization: Basic auth here'
              ),
    ));
            
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    
    curl_close($curl);
    $result = json_decode($response, true); // true turns it into an array
}
```

payment information rebill contains all the variables needed for the curl, which works on the shopping cart page. however, when I put the curl function in the redirecturl of the payment gateway, the variables seems to be empty. the variables gets their data from sessions. does session only work when you access the page? does it not work on background?

Comment: The server identifies the session you're in based on a cookie sent by the browser (which was given to it by the server when it first accessed the site after the browser was opened by the user). So yeah if you're getting a request from your payment gateway then clearly that won't have any connection to an end-user's session. The incoming request is going to need to send some sort of ID which you can then use to retrieve the necessary data from a database or file.

Comment: Please clarify, the _user_ gets redirected to this URL in their browser, we are not talking about a server-side callback here, correct? Then your problem is most likely with the [`SameSite`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite) attribute of your session cookie.

Comment: there are 3 steps in my website. I am storing all needed request parameters on payment-information-rebill.php. the request parameters include a redirecturl, where the user will be redirected after the transaction is successful, notificationurl, where the response will be posted. what I'm trying to do is set a curl function in notification url calling the endpoint that will verify the enrollment so that the users will not click another button. but the variables I've set in payment-information-rebill.php is all empty, causing the veirication process to fail since parameters are empty.

Comment: Yes, then you need to go look into `SameSite`, because a _wrong_ setting for that, makes you lose your session in this context.

Comment: If I set the samesite to none, will it work now on background?

Comment: You say the curl code you've shown us is in the page called by the notification URL...how is that URL triggered? By a redirect in the user's browser, or by a request straight from the payment provider's server (like a callback / webhook)? It will wasn't totally clear, from your description.

Comment: However if cookies do indeed turn out to be the issue, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite tells you what all the same site settings do

Comment: @ADyson, the user will start in the shopping cart. there's a button there for enrollment of card. after clicking that button, it will redirect the user to a gateway hosted page where the user will input his/her card details. I am using the enrollment endpoint in the first curl triggered by button in shopping cart. the enrollment needs to be verified using a second endpoint which I want to put in the notification url so that the user will not have to push another button for verifying the enrollment. the notification url does not open but only accessed by the gateway after enrollment.

Comment: So if it's only accessed by the gateway, not opened by the user, then you can't use sessions in the notification URL. Goes back to my first comment, then.